# jquery do something when window resized

Tags: jquery

i am have trouble combining two scripts together they work as two scripts but i need them to work as one one script is to make a dropdown menu appear and the other changes the dropdown menu to a hyperlink what i need the script to do is when window is say less than 520 that it turns the dropdown menu to just a link
hey is what i have

```
$(window).resize(function()
{
    if ($(window).width() < 520)
    {
        $("#documentLink").attr("href", "http://www.w3schools.com/jquery");
    }
    else
    {
        $(document).ready(function()
        {
            $("#documentLink").click(function()
            {
                $("#documentcontainer").fadeToggle(300);
                return false;
            });
            $(document).click(function()
            {
                $("#documentcontainer").hide();
            });
            $("#documentcontainer").click(function()
            {
                return false;
            });
        });
    }
});
```

the first part works when the window is resized but the last part of the script is not sorry for the way my question is layed out not good at asking question

Answer (score 0):

It is very unlikely that your callback for `$(document).ready` will ever be triggered - The `ready` event on `document` is fired once when the document is ready, but you are attaching this event when the user resize the window (event which will be fired after the `ready` event).

What you should do is check in your callback if the size of the window is less than `520` and do what is necessary after:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#documentLink").click(function(e) {
        if ($(window).width() >= 520) {
            e.preventDefault () ;
            $("#documentcontainer").fadeToggle(300);
            return false;
        }
        return true ;
    });
    $(document).click(function({
        $("#documentcontainer").hide();
    });
    $("#documentcontainer").click(function() {
        return false;
    });
});
```

Here, I am assuming that your `#documentLink` is already a `a` tag with the corresponding `href`.

Comment: documentLink has a href of # and that what the top script for turning it in to a page url on my website

Comment: @aaronhead You could change it to `http://www.w3schools.com/jquery`, returning false is the `click` callback will prevent the URL redirection.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can try something like this,

```
     $(document).ready(function()
     {
        $(window).resize(function()
        {
            if ($(window).width() < 520)
            {
                $("#documentLink").attr("href", "http://www.w3schools.com/jquery");
            }
          });

//READY CODE HERE
                    $("#documentLink").click(function()
                    {
                      if ($(window).width() > 520)  //CHECK WIDTH IN EVENT HNDLR.
                      {
                        $("#documentcontainer").fadeToggle(300);
                        return false;
                      }
                    });


                   //MORE CODE HERE...



        });
    });
```